# How to exclude properties in EF 7?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have below type

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

I have below context

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().Ignore(x => x.Url);
    }
}
```

I am trying out how to exclude Properties using fluent API. I am assuming that when we exclude the property of a type in EF, it wont be able to read/save that property to database.

In my code sample below, I am using InMemory DB & have excluded Url Property.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase();

            using (var db = new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
            {
                var blog = new Blog { BlogId = 1, Url = "MyUrl" };

                db.Blogs.Add(blog);
                db.SaveChanges();

                foreach (var item in db.Blogs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.BlogId);

                    Console.WriteLine(item.Url);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }


        }
    }
```

In output , I can see that EF is able to read & save that property information

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. The problem is that you're misinterpreting the code and the results.

You create your `blog` object with this property values:

```
var blog = new Blog { BlogId = 1, Url = "MyUrl" };
```

So, this object is in memory, and tracked by the context. As required, the context is not tracking the `Url` property, but that property is already in memory, in your `Blog` instance.

Your code does nothing to remove or change the `blog` object or its `url` from this instance. And then shows it in the console.

Nothing strange is going on. But your code is not testing if the `Url` was saved or not to the in memory database.

If you want to test that, try reading the object from the in memory database in a new `blog` instance, show it in the console, and you'll see a null `Url` as you expected.